# In cypress, How to select options when there is no select option?

Tags: cypress, react-select

I have just started exploring Cypress and came across such a problem:

**Is it possible to select/ or set a value in a dropdown box**?, when **there is no select tag in the html code**

The data (options) are from a global variables in react.

For example lets take this simple piece of code

```html
<div class="row simulation_config">
    <div class="required form-group"><label for="cc_w02qmy5l5" class="">currency</label>
        <div class="Select css-b62m3t-container"><span id="react-select-4-live-region" class="css-1f43avz-a11yText-A11yText"></span><span aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="false" aria-relevant="additions text" class="css-1f43avz-a11yText-A11yText"></span>
            <div class="Select__control css-1s2u09g-control">
                <div class="Select__value-container css-319lph-ValueContainer">
                    <div class="Select__placeholder css-14el2xx-placeholder" id="react-select-4-placeholder">Select...</div>
                    <div class="Select__input-container css-6j8wv5-Input" data-value=""><input class="Select__input" autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" id="cc_w02qmy5l5" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" type="text" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="combobox" value="" style="color: inherit; background: 0px center; opacity: 1; width: 100%; grid-area: 1 / 2 / auto / auto; font: inherit; min-width: 2px; border: 0px; margin: 0px; outline: 0px; padding: 0px;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="Select__indicators css-1hb7zxy-IndicatorsContainer">
                    <div class="Select__indicator Select__dropdown-indicator css-tlfecz-indicatorContainer" aria-hidden="true"><span class="connect-icon connect-icon-caret-down"></span></div>
                </div>
            </div><input name="currency" type="hidden" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="required form-group"><label for="cc_s0ibe93kp" class="">inflationRate</label><input id="cc_s0ibe93kp" name="inflationRate" class="form-control dirty" type="text" value="2.3%" inputmode="numeric"></div>
</div>
```

How the code looks like in react side:

```html
<div className="row simulation_config">
          <FormSelect
            key="input-currency"
            name="currency"
            label="currency"
            required
            value={currency}
            data={currencies}
            onChange={e => {
              selectCurrencyHandler(e, setData)
            }}
            data-cy="currency"
          />
```

Here is what I have tried

```js
cy.get('.Select__input').first().click().select('USD') // ERROR: cy.select() can only be called on a <select>

cy.get('[name="currency"]').first().focus().type('USD',{ force: true }) // Doesnt show me the value in display
```

Example screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you'd use the `data-cy="currency"` attribute to get the select, but in this case React doesn't pass that on to the web page.

I would suggest `<div className="row simulation_config">` is a good place to start.

To select one of the options, to avoid a flaky test specify "option" in the selector

```js
cy.get('div.row.simulation_config')
  .find('.Select')
  .click()                             

cy.contains('[id*="option"]', 'USD')
  .click()
```

Comment: I see that you use find('.Select') ; But I dont really a class called "Select" exactly in the html. So, may I know does it means it is going to find out all class name contains "Select"

Coz right now, I got a "4 match" in cypress studio after hitting .find 

As for cy.contains('[id*="option"]', 'USD') , could you explain a bit here? Coz I dont see any option tag in the html code above, so I dont understand where it is referencing

Comment: Aparr from that, in cypress studio, it doesnt suggest me to cy.get('div.row.simulation_config') ; is it sometimes it is the case that we need to determine our selector?

Comment: Or, if it is too much to answer, I would just like to ask what contains('[id*="option"]', 'USD') means? coz I dont see any tag/keywords indicating 'option'

Comment: I guess you actually need to try it. The option of this control are hard to find, so actually running the test is your best option.

Comment: but where do you see '[id*="option"]' from the above html? There is no clue to see '[id*="option"]' is hooked to the selection ?

Comment: Can you see the currency texts there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dropdown text and click on it.

```js
cy.get('selector').click() //Expands the dropdown
cy.contains('EUR').click() //selects EUR
```